# I have to use this template for my thesis, but there is no dots in table of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, templates

I have to use this template for my thesis, but there are no dots in the list of figures and list of table, I tried to contact the author who creates the template, but no respose.

Hopeful, someone can help me with this template. [Here](https://github.com/darrnshn/thesis) is the original code for this template.

Please let me know how to fix it! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please paste a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) here instead of a link to external websites, as the links may be broken in the future.

Comment: There's something not quite right.  "I have to use this template" should mean "this template is exactly the way we want it, and you won't need to change anything".  That is clearly not the case.  Could you elaborate on why you have to use this template?  Who says so?  Who says that you need dots in the list of figures and list of tables?  Are you talking about the dots between the table's caption and its page number, or are you talking about the dot that comes between the chapter number and the table number?

Comment: I will echo @Teepeemm's comment: If you really must use the template `usydthesis.cls` -- the class file appears to have been updated last in 2003, and it seems to insist on using versions of various LaTeX packages that are even older than 2003 -- then *you* should not have to fiddle with any structural elements of your document, such as the presence or absence of dot-leaders in the List of Figures and the List of Tables. Incidentally, you should really go back to the folks you make you use such an ancient and apparently unmaintained template and ask to be allowed to use a different template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cheapest solution I could find to produce the filling dots in the list of figures and list of tables is by adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@figure{\@tocline{1}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{1.5pc}{}}
\let\l@table=\l@figure
\makeatother
```

to your preamble.

The class modifies `\@tocline` in such a way that if the first argument to `\@tocline` is greater than `0` you get filling dots. The default definition of the two in `amsbook.cls` (upon which `usydthesis` is based) has `\def\l@figure{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{1.5pc}{}}`. `usydthesis` also redefines `\@tocline` itself and it can be verified that the change from `0` to `1` does not change the output apart from the dots in the current setup.

I added a few example tables to the `thesis.tex` in the GitHub repository and with the fout lines from above added to the preamble obtained

[image: LOT with dotfill]

---

Let me please reiterate the sentiment in the comments that it is *completely* unreasonable to expect you (force you) to use a template which (1) does not produce the expected output *or* (2) is not actively maintained any more.

I also have my doubts about the general quality of the template. For one I believe it loads far too many packages. It also loads `hyperref` too early and makes very liberal use of `\def`, where `\newcommand` might be safer. The structure with several sub-includes and copies (possibly modified or outdated) of standard packages also makes the template unwieldy and very hard to understand. Especially for beginners the thing is just too overwhelming.

Comment: +1! Nice work!!

Comment: No words can describe how I feel right now, Thanks!